# Computing the arc length of the graph $y=\sqrt{x-x^2}+\arcsin(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, arc-length

Computing the arc length of the graph $y=\sqrt{x-x^2}+\arcsin(\sqrt{x})$

Is this done right?

I found the interval of this function which is $[0,1]$
I know the arc length formula is $$ L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$$

The derivative of the function is $$y'=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}$$
and the the square of $y'$ is $$(y')^2=\frac{1-x}{x}$$

When I plug in these results on the integral I get $$L=\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}d}x$$ 
with the substitution of $\sqrt{x}=t$ we get the result $L=2$

This is the graph of the function

[image]

Thanks, @DougM for pointing out my mistake

Comment: Check your differentiation.  Get that right and everything that follows will be much simpler.

Comment: Oh wow, what mistake. Thanks for pointing it though. It's so easy now